# Getting authoritative nameservers with dns_get_record() results in $authns being null

Tags: php, dns

I want to get the authoritative nameservers for a domain. [`dns_get_record()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dns-get-record.php) seems straight forward and should be able to populate the authoritative nameservers into `$authns`.

If I run the example from the manual:

```
<?php
$result = dns_get_record("php.net", DNS_ANY, $authns, $addtl);
echo "Result = ";
var_dump($result);
echo "Auth NS = ";
var_dump($authns);
echo "Additional = ";
var_dump($addtl);
```

I get the following output:

```
---snipped---
Auth NS =

null

Additional =

null
```

Why is it that authns and additional records are null?

I am running PHP 5.5.3 on Ubuntu 13.04 64-bit.

Comment: What PHP version and what OS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

If you want `NS` records you should ask for them explicitly.

When you send an `ANY` request to your local recursive server you will only get the records that are in the recursive server's cache at that time, although if there are no such records your query will trigger an upstream `ANY` request to the authoritative server for that domain.

Also, in an `ANY` query all returned records will be found in the "answer" section, not in the "authority" section.

Comment: Tried `dns_get_record("php.net", DNS_NS, $authns, $addtl);` but still the same problem :(

Comment: If you ask for the `NS` records they'll still be in the answer section (since that's the explicit question you asked).  `NS` records tend to mostly only appear in the authority section of responses from authoritative servers back to recursive servers, and may not appear in responses sent from recursive servers back to stub resolvers.

Answer (score 1):

Example :

```
$NS=array('8.8.8.8');
$dns_NS_array=dns_get_record("google.com", DNS_NS, $NS);
print_r($dns_NS_array);
```

Output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [host] => google.com
            [class] => IN
            [ttl] => 343459
            [type] => NS
            [target] => ns1.google.com
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [host] => google.com
            [class] => IN
            [ttl] => 343459
            [type] => NS
            [target] => ns3.google.com
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [host] => google.com
            [class] => IN
            [ttl] => 343459
            [type] => NS
            [target] => ns2.google.com
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [host] => google.com
            [class] => IN
            [ttl] => 343459
            [type] => NS
            [target] => ns4.google.com
        )

)
```

Comment: Fatal error: Only variables can be passed by reference